# How to convert the time from 00:00 to 24:00 in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a columns in dataframe with start time and endtime in 24hr format,after converting it with to_datetime I want to get the delta between start time and end time, but in case if start time is 23:00 and end time is 00:00 then it gives -1 day, so I want to make 00:00 to 24:00 instead and then get delta.

I have

```
s1 = pd.Series(['02/18/2016', '23:00:00', '00:00:00'])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1)],  columns =  ["Date", "Start_Time", "End_Time"])

>>> df
Date       Start_Time   End_Time
02/18/2016  23:00:00    00:00:00
```

Required Output

```
Date        Start_Time   End_Time  Diff
02/18/2016  23:00:00     00:00:00  01:00:00
```

Comment: Technically speaking 00:00 is the following day, so how about including the date? Any other solution would make 00:00 ambiguous.

Comment: i thought of it and that would work however since column has only time .. and to_Datetime returned same date for all the records.

Comment: is there a date stored anywhere else? What about two records 24:00 and 00:00 separated by ten days of difference.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your input and expected output is?

Comment: you can python strftime library

Comment: You really need to store more than just a time to do any sort of date comparison.

Comment: strftime will format but still keep time as 00:00 .. i do not see any format in strftime that will return 24: Let me know.

Comment: s1 = pd.Series(['02/18/2016', '23:00:00', '00:00:00'])


df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1)],  columns =  ["Date", "Start_Time", "End_Time"])
df

Comment: need to add a column with difference in start time and end time

Comment: @jigishc you can edit your question and add the information, formatted, there.

Comment: What if the end time was 24 hours from the start time?  How would you deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all rows where `End_Time` equals `'00:00:00'` and convert it to a Timedelta of `+1 days`:

```
df['Diff'] = pd.to_timedelta((df['End_Time'] == '00:00:00').astype(int), unit='d')
# 0   1 days
# Name: End_Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Then convert `Start_Time` and `End_Time` to dates:

```
for col in ['Start_Time', 'End_Time']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df[col])
```

and augment the `End_Time` by 1 day if it use to equal `'00:00:00'`:

```
df['End_Time'] += df['Diff']
```

Now you can compute `Diff` as normal:

```
df['Diff'] = df['End_Time'] - df['Start_Time']
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['02/18/2016', '23:00:00', '00:00:00']], 
                  columns = ["Date", "Start_Time", "End_Time"]) 

df['Diff'] = pd.to_timedelta((df['End_Time'] == '00:00:00').astype(int), unit='d')
for col in ['Start_Time', 'End_Time']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df[col])
df['End_Time'] += df['Diff']
df['Diff'] = df['End_Time'] - df['Start_Time']
print(df)
```

yields

```
         Date          Start_Time   End_Time     Diff
0  02/18/2016 2016-02-18 23:00:00 2016-02-19 01:00:00
```